# Azure Role Caching - Expiration time not working

Tags: azure, azure-caching

I'm running role cache in my Azure WebRole.
 When I insert an object in the cache, I specify a timespan of 15 seconds, but the object expires 1 minute and a half after inserting.

The question is: Is there a min-value for the expiration time.. can it be 15 seconds?

**Update:** 
When I say that the object does not expire in the specified time, I mean that I don't receive the expected "remove callback" in the configured time. I have the following configuration:

```
 DataCacheFactoryConfiguration config = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
            config.NotificationProperties = new DataCacheNotificationProperties(1000, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));


            cacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory(config);
            cacheAbsolute = cacheFactory.GetCache("absolute");



            foreach (CacheAbsoluteRegion reg in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CacheAbsoluteRegion)))
            {
                cacheAbsolute.CreateRegion(reg.ToString());
                cacheAbsolute.AddRegionLevelCallback(reg.ToString(), DataCacheOperations.RemoveItem, new DataCacheNotificationCallback(RemoveCallback));
            }
```

After I add an object with a timespan of 15 seconds, the callback is called between 1 and 2 minutes after the insert.

Comment: Can you post the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.NamedCaches string from your settings?

Comment: {&quot;caches&quot;:[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;default&quot;,&quot;policy&quot;:{&quot;eviction&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:0},&quot;expiration&quot;:{&quot;defaultTTL&quot;:1,&quot;isExpirable&quot;:true,&quot;type&quot;:2},&quot;serverNotification&quot;:{&quot;isEnabled&quot;:true}},&quot;secondaries&quot;:0},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;absolute&quot;,&quot;policy&quot;:{&quot;eviction&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:0},&quot;expiration&quot;:{&quot;defaultTTL&quot;:10,&quot;isExpirable&quot;:true,&quot;type&quot;:1},&quot;serverNotification&quot;:{&quot;isEnabled&quot;:true}},&quot;secondaries&quot;:0}]}

Comment: There are 2 named caches, one has sliding expiration and the other absolute expiration.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using something like:

```
cache.Add("item", "value", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
```

And that your cache is setup for "absolute" expiration, not "sliding".  [Read more here...](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I'm adding a timespan of 15 seconds and it is setup for absolute expiration

Comment: Weird, switching to absolute expiry fixed the issue for me. Not sure what the nature of expiry has anything to do with the eviction itself. Logically it should be possible to have sliding + expiration ...